# Not evaluating an expression when using cat

Tags: bash

I have one bash script that is designed to output another bash script. I am using `cat`. I want to evaluate some of the expressions in output script, but not others.

```
PROJECT=myproject

cat << EOF > create_dir.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATE=`date '+%y%m%d-%H%M'`
mkdir $PROJECT/\$DATE
EOF
```

The resulting `create_dir.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATE=171123-1834

mkdir myproject/$DATE
```

The result that I want is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATE=`date '+%y%m%d-%H%M'`

mkdir myproject/$DATE
```

How can I modify this script so that the expression following `DATE=` is not evaluated, while at the same time ensuring that `$PROJECT` is evaluated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the '`' symbols since they mean "execute this code". So that line should look like:

```
DATE=\`date '+%y%m%d-%H%M'\`
```

Comment: I'ld maybe recommend to use `$( ... )` instead of the `` ` `` in order to have to escape only one symbol `/$`

Answer (score 5):

`cat << \EOF`

If the label is quoted then the here document is taken as is. Or else quote the backquotes in the here document.

The relevant part of the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html) is:

> If any part  of *word*  is  quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on *word*,  and the lines in the  here-document  are  not  expanded.   If *word* is unquoted,  all  lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion,  command  substitution,  and   arithmetic   expansion,   the character  sequence  `\`<newline> is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

Note that this solution will copy the here document verbatim; to have some expansions done and others not done the only solution is to use `\` to quote those constructions which are not be expanded.

Comment: +1; Double quotes around EOF works well too. Example: `cat > file.asc << "EOF"`

Comment: As do single quotes.

Comment: This solution sounds interesting having only parts of EOF evaluated for a similar case I have. Could you please provide a complete example using the OPs snipped?

Comment: @derHugo: Exactly as writen by the OP, just replacing `EOF` with `\EOF`. The contents of the here document is then copied verbatim.

Comment: But he doesn't want that but the $PROJECT shall be evaluated.

Comment: @derHugo: You are right. Added emphasis that this solution copies the here document verbatim.

Comment: @AlexP oh than your answer was kind of misleading .. I thought you had found a solution different from `'EOF'` where it was possible to "reactivate" the evaluation for specific parts of the EOF.